# What is commonly known about Bruenor Battlehammer?

Tags: dnd-5e, npc, forgotten-realms, lore

My Fighter is a proud Dwarf from the Mithral Halls. He is a history buff, with proficiency in history, a personality trait of "I know all the stories," and a *perfectly healthy* obsession with the adventures of Bruenor Battlehammer.

I've read up on the [Forgotten Realms wiki](http://forgottenrealms.wikia.com/wiki/Bruenor_Battlehammer) about Bruenor, so as a player I have pretty good knowledge about him. My character is really into this stuff, so certainly he knows more than average characters do; however, it's unclear how much of this information would be known to a resident of the Forgotten Realms and how much is only known to readers of the lore.

What major highlights about Bruenor Battlehammer's adventures and life would be known to a character beset by hero worship? Our campaign takes place somewhen around 1484 DR.

As an example, I'm pretty sure everyone knows he was King. Twice. But then he faked his death—is that common knowledge? Then he actually died—how about that? And he was resurrected; I can only assume nobody has heard about that yet.

Comment: I have a feeling this could be flagged as "primarily opinion-based" because there's no hard answer for it.

Comment: I'm not sure about primarily opinion-based, but it certainly might be unanswerable. A good answer, best as I can tell, would need to cite scenes from FR canon where FR natives were trading Bruenor stories, or something like that. Since this question has gone three years without a good answer, perhaps there isn't any such information extant in the FR canon?

Comment: To be pedantic, he was reincarnated rather than resurrected.

Answer (score 8):

I'd say all of Bruenor's major deeds and some of the minor ones, but only up until he left the throne for his final adventure with Drizzt.
So I'd say for a guideline the stuff that happened in the *Crystal Shard*.
The story about Bruenor and the black dragon when he first returns to Mithral Hall.
The war with the dark elves, and the war with the orcs and the frost giants, where he once again very nearly died.
The Treaty of Garumn's Gorge with the orcs.

These things I would say at the very least would be stories some dwarf obsessed with Bruenor would know. Although because your character is obsessed it would make sense for you to use obscure stories. Like the one about Lady Alustriel nursing him back to health after his scuffle with the black dragon.

I'd say the faking his own death wouldn't be common knowledge because only a few knew about it. Although this was common among dwarven kings, they would fake their own death for a chance to go on a final adventure pretty sure its mentioned in the series several times. Although I just remembered that the dwarves from Icewind Dale know about Bruenor's last adventure in Gauntlgrym so its very likely you could use this as well, as most wouldn't know it but someone who is a history buff could probably find out.